# How can I get the division and product of specific lines from a file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get division of 1st line to 2nd line and product 2nd line to 4th line from a file. But I couldn't do it. I got this result in the output file: inf[1]/inf[2] inf[2]*inf[4]. How can I get the division of 1st line to 2nd line and product 2nd line to 4th?

**Input file:**

```
2233.3000
2190.0508
2172.2361
2189.3050
2199.3000
2193.2461
```

**My code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

result="input.xvg"
while read line
do
   division=$line[1]/$line[2];
   product=$line[2]*$line[4]
   echo "$division $product" > output.xvg

done < input.xvg
```

Comment: please edit your question to include expected output from your sample data file. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- bash needs some extra syntax to do arithmetic. -- [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)
- it can only do arithmetic with integers, so you'll need to call out to a program that can to floating point math, `bc` is a handy program for that.
- to read the lines of a file into an array, use `mapfile` (which creates a zero-indexed array) -- [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile)
- you need to add braces to extract the array values: `${line[1]}` not `$line[1]` -- [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t line < input.xvg
division=$(bc -l <<< "${line[0]} / ${line[1]}")
product=$(bc -l <<< "${line[1]} * ${line[3]}")
echo "$division $product" > output.xvg
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I am just wondering can't we use 'while loop` for this calculation?

Comment: Because `while read` only allows you to see a single line at a time. Imagine you're reading the first line of the file: you cannot know what the 4th line is, right? You have to read all the lines or at least the first 4 before you can do your calculations. If you want to use `while read`, you have to save the current line into an array, then do your calculations outside the while loop.